# How can I cythonize a function which works on strings?

Tags: python, cython

I have a function which takes an array of letters (called `letters`), and constructs permutations of the elements of that array according to the entries in the list `walks`.  Finally, it checks if any of those permutations are in another array(called `words`).  Here is a minimal example

```
letters = 'resenntesayhresb'
letters = np.char.array(list(letters))
walks = [[0,1,5,6], [1,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]]
words = np.array(['rent','house'])

def compute(walks, letters, words):

    w =  []
    for i,walk in enumerate(walks):
        w.append(''.join(letters[walk]))

    return np.intersect1d(words, np.array(w))


compute(walks, letters, words)
```

I would like to cythonize this function because I'd like to apply it to a `walk` array of 16 million entries and a words array of half a million entries.

How can I cythonize this function?  I've tried the cell magic but there doesn't seem to be a speedup.

Comment: What does your cython code look like?